# WildFly 9 deploying simple webapp but 404

Tags: web-applications, wildfly-9

I have a simple hello world webapp that when I run it in tomcat with the url `http://localhost:8080/na/environment` works fine; The same war in wildfly 9 does not work, I get a 404 error.

Googling it I found a WildFly project requires 2 files(beans.xml and jboss-web.xml), I just added to the project but still is not working.

My wildldFly admin console says the war is deployed and enabled

[image: wildFly console]

This is the structure of my project:

[image: project structure]

And the content of my file `jboss-web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
  <context-root>/</context-root>
 </jboss-web>
```

The `beans.xml` is empty(still don't get what is its porpoise).

Finally, the code of my servlet(and only class) is:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/environment")
public class Environment extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                                                       IOException {
    response.getWriter().append("Hello");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                                                        IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
    }



}
```

I tried using:

```
http://localhost:9990/na/environment/
http://localhost:9990/na.war/environment/
http://localhost:9990/environment/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the context to be `na` you need to change your jboss-web.xml to use `na` as the root context.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/na</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

If you change the runtime name when you deploy that should also work. You could also override the `<finalName>na</finalName>` in your pom as well.